# Warning.js?6327:33 Warning: Unknown prop `store` on <provider> tag

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router

In my project, I am trying to combine two reducers. But whenever I try to combine them using  combineReducers({}), my props become undefined and my state:

[image]

(from store.getState()) turns out to be two objects name after my reducers. See my reducer setup:

[image]

[image]

Comment: did you forget to include your reducer setup?

Comment: Hi, it's really hard to understand your problem without code examples. Please add code examples that are [minimal and reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

Although all the necessary codes are not included, I suspect the error is caused by incorrect `mapStateToProps` function. I bumped into similar issue and spend some hours investigating the problem. The right approach is immediately after you use `combineReducers` to go and refactor the following portion to include the appropriate reducer:

```
export default combineReducers({
  example: exampleReducer,
  second: secondReducer
});
```

example will have to be adjusted accordingly here, so that the Props are working smoothly.

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        ads: state.example.ads,
        quizes: state.example.quizes
        };
}
```

The crucial moment is `ads: state.ads,` becomes `ads: state.example.ads,`

Hope it may be useful for somebody.